# Export Instagram photos without login

Tags: export, instagram

I have an Instagram account. I've forgotten the password and have not been able to reset it. *Essentially, assume the account isn't mine as far as logging in is concerned.*

How can I get all my pictures? I don't need comments, followers, or anything other than the JPGs.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways that you can approach this:

1. Third Party Apps

   There are a slew of unaffiliated third party apps that can do the job for you on your mobile phone according to what kind of OS you are using. You would have to specifically use one that can do so without you having to log in considering that you have no access to your account. Please take a look at which app would be more applicable for you. It would also be best if you could create a spare account or have a friend willing to share his or her account with you as some apps would require some form of logging in (not necessarily with the account from which you are trying to retrieve photos).
2. Third-Party Websites

   Some websites, such as [InstaGrabbr](http://instagrabbr.com) and [Dinsta](http://dinsta.com), will also be able to help you retrieve your photos in a similar manner. Except that it would be more convenient to do so on your computer or laptop. Some websites will also allow you to download all the photos with just one click making it a more hassle free option.
3. Browser

   You can also gain access to the photos on your browser. This would be done differently for different browsers. But what you would want to do is load your profile on the Instagram website, and then find the directory to your photos from Inspect Element or View Page Source browser options.